# Add numbers part of a string using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Can I add the numbers I get in a string format using the below code:

`Size = a.Type == "Machines" ?string.Join(",", a.Info.DiskInfo.Select(b => b.Size)) : null,`

The output of this code is: `"50.00 GiB, 16.00 GiB"`, for example.

I decided to first remove the units from it so that I can add the numbers straight away. Therefore, I changed the code to:

`Size = a.Type == "Machines" ? string.Join(",", a.Info.DiskInfo.Select(b => b.Size).Select(c => Regex.Replace(c, "[^0-9.]", ""))) : null,`

Now, the output is: "50.00, 16.00"

How do I add these numbers which are in a string using LINQ, to get "66.00" as the output?

Comment: Since it is a string, you could try `.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(n => Convert.ToSingle(n.Trim())).Sum();` You could probably re-work that to avoid the `string.Join` at the beginning.

Comment: Hey @RonBeyer.. it is IEnumerable<string>.. I tried to do the below but I do not get nay output on Postman... `ToString().Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(n => Convert.ToSingle(n.Trim())).Sum()`

Comment: Then use `.First()` at the beginning of that, ie: `.First().Split(...)...` Don't use `.ToString` before it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the statement to:

```
Size = a.Type == "Machines" 
  ? a.Info.DiskInfo
     .Select(b => b.Size)
     .Select(c => Regex.Replace(c, "[^0-9.]", "")))
     .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
     .Select(x => Convert.ToDecimal(x.Trim()))
     .Sum()
  : null,
```

For clarity on the LINQ pipeline:

```
Size = a.Type == "Machines"  
  ? a.Info.DiskInfo // object
     .Select(b => b.Size) // IEnumerable<string>
     .Select(c => Regex.Replace(c, "[^0-9.]", ""))) // IEnumerable<string>
     .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)) // IEnumerable<string>
     .Select(x => Convert.ToDecimal(x.Trim())) // IEnumerable<decimal>
     .Sum() // single decimal
     .ToString() // single string
  : null,
```

Comment: I'd upvote this if you put the entire thing in there, and got rid of the `string.Join` at the beginning.

Comment: @RonBeyer.. I am using string.join because Size being used in the select statement is a IEnumerable<string>: `Select(b => b.Size)`.. So, not using string.Join() gives me an error.

Comment: The LINQ statements form a pipeline, so what started as `IEnumerable<string>` gets converted to `IEnumberable<decimal>` by the last `Select` the a single `decimal` by the `Sum`. You could convert it back to a string by adding `ToString()` after the `Sum`